# How to set up a Laravel multi-tenancy queue using Redis?

Tags: laravel-8

We have a Laravel multi-tenant application, where there are individual databases for each tenant. Need to know to pass the database information to the queue worker job when using redis as queue worker.
We have to connect to the respective database based on this information passed to the worker. Looking for an option to pass this information generally rather than on each dispatch event.

JobDispatched event track